# Want to make a button that clears a form after saving the data in a form as an object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

So I'm doing a project in Ruby, and I want to have people fill out a form , which will be an answer to a question, and be able to make another answer to that same question. To accomplish this, I would like to save an answer object to my database using the data in the form, and then clear the form. I've yet to figure out how to do that using a link_to tag.

Here is the object controller:

```html
class AnswersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @answers = Answer.all
  end
  
  def new
    @answer = Answer.new
  end
  
  def show
    @answer = Answer.find(params[:id])
  end
  
  def create
    Question.order (:created_at)
    @question = Question.last
    @answer = @question.answers.build(answer_params)
    #if @answer.save
    #  redirect_to root_url
    #else
    #  render static_pages/home
    #end
    redirect_to root_url
  end  
  
  private
    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def answer_params
      params.require(:answer).permit(:content, :correct)
    end
end
```

Here is the new.html.erb:

```html
<% provide(:title, 'New Answers') %>
<h1>New Answers</h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <%= form_for(@answer) do |f| %>
      <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
      <%= f.label @content%>
      <%= f.text_field @content, class: 'form-control' %>
      
      <%= f.label @correct%>
      <input type="checkbox" name="Correct?" value="Correct?" checked> This answer is correct<br>    
      <%= f.submit "Finish creating Quiz", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
      <%= link_to "Create more Questions", createQuestion_path, class: "btn btn-primary" %>
      <%= link_to "Create more Answers", createAnswer_path, class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated. Please let me know if you need anything else to further understand the problem

Thanks!

Comment: The question is not clear to me. If you what the user to see a blank form after successfully creating a record, why don't you just `redirect_to :new` in the `if @answer.save` branch?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to redirect back after the form has been submitted. But if you want to this dynamically, you'll have to add some JavaScript on top.

So, for example, you could make an AJAX POST request on submission, perhaps add some indication of that action happening and then clear the fields using Jquery or plain JavaScript.

There are meriad of ways to this, you can read more on this [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html). It might look something like this:

### Controller

```
def create
  respond_to do |format|
    @question = Question.last
    @answer = @question.answers.build(answer_params)

    if @answer.save
      format.json { head :no_content }
    else
      format.json do
        render json: {
          errors: @answer.errors.full_messages
        }, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end
end
```

### View

```
<% provide(:title, 'New Answers') %>
<h1>New Answers</h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <%= form_with(@answer) do |f| %>
      <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
      <%= f.label @content%>
      <%= f.text_field @content, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.label @correct%>
      <input type="checkbox" name="Correct?" value="Correct?" checked> This answer is correct<br>    
      <%= f.submit "Finish creating Quiz", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
      <%= link_to "Create more Questions", createQuestion_path, class: "btn btn-primary" %>
      <%= link_to "Create more Answers", createAnswer_path, class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

### JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#new_answer").on("ajax:success", function(e, data, status, xhr) {
    $('#yourForm').trigger("reset");
  }).on("ajax:error", function(e, xhr, status, error) {
    $("#new_answer").append("<p>ERROR</p>");
  });
});
```